# WP function/filter for modifying http headers?

Tags: api, headers

Is there a dedicated WP function, action or filter to use when adding/modifying the HTTP headers?

For now I just hook a PHP header() call into the WP 'init' hook like this:

```
add_action('init', 'add_header_xua');
function add_header_xua(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');    
    }
}
```

But is this the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The init action is the wrong place to do it. A better place would be at template_redirect, so that you only affect the front end view of the site and not the admin areas.

Comment: good point regarding the hook, but apart from that, is calling the 'raw' header() function (using the right hook) the correct way, or is there a wp wrapper that should be used for this? Calling header directly only allows for adding to the headers, not modifying them, like it would be possible with a filter (like when you want to manipulate the body class)

Comment: header() is the only way. However, it does have a second parameter that will let you replace existing headers instead of adding to them. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 15):

Here is the code I've used, based on the original question and on Dominic P's answer...

```
/*
 * Modify HTTP header
 */
function add_header_xua($headers) {

    // var_dump($headers); #=> if you want to see the current headers...  

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=edge,chrome=1';    
    }

    return $headers;     
}
add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_header_xua');
```

Once you've added that code to your functions.php file, you can check it works by running a test at http://web-sniffer.net/ to ensure the HTTP headers have indeed changed.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's been a while, but if anyone else stumbles on this, I found a WordPress hook specifically for modifying HTTP headers. The hook is `wp_headers` and it's called in the [wp class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp.php?rev=23345#L377).

The first argument passed is an array of headers with the header name as the key. The second argument is a reference to the wp class object.

Comment: There is another hook: `send_headers`. I do not see any "wp_headers" on the [hook list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. You checkout the [wp_headers filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/) here.

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that there are "internal" hooks (such as wp_headers), and "public" hooks (such as "send_headers"). "internal" hooks are more prone to be changed in future releases. "public" hooks are deemed more "stable". But I may just be wrong here, I don't find any source to back up this feeling I got from various researches I did on hooks.

Comment: That is very possible, but in this case it looks like the two hooks simply perform different functions.  `send_headers` is an action that fires after the headers are sent while `wp_headers` is a filter on the headers that is applied before they are sent.

Comment: well...if the fact that only [`send_headers`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers) has a codex page is any indication of which to use...

Comment: Keep in mind though that the WordPress team is trying to transition [away from the codex](https://make.wordpress.org/docs/2013/06/19/docs-sprint-results-and-roadmap/) towards the new [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/)

Comment: `wp_headers` is a filter inside the send_headers() function. You'll want to use the `send_headers` filter for this particular question at hand as it will take precedence over `wp_headers`. It's important to note that `send_headers` runs after doing a check for the "Last-Modified" header. By using `send_headers` over `wp_headers` we can ensure that our `X-UA-Compatible` tag will be sent even if the page has been statically cached where `wp_headers` wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: @Bryan, that's an interesting explanation. I'm curious though: if a page is statically cached and it's served _before_ `wp_headers` runs, how could `send_headers` work if it runs _after_ `wp_headers`? Wouldn't execution of the entire `send_headers()` function, along with the rest of WordPress, be skipped?

Comment: Hey Dominic, if you look inside the [send_headers() function at this point](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src//wp-includes/class-wp.php#L448) you can see where `wp_headers` is introduced and after that how the function continues by checking "Last-Modified" and then the [send_headers do_action_ref_array( 'send_headers', array( &$this ) );](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src//wp-includes/class-wp.php#L485). So by using the action we are hooking into it after the check if the page was cached.

Comment: Dominic, I actually only learned all this today after I asked a nearly [identical question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214028/43806). `send_headers` is actually the way demonstrated in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers) does it as well.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what the `send_headers()` function is doing in the `Last-Modified` bit. All that code block does is determine whether the `Last-Modified` header should be removed, and if so it removes it. If full page caching is being used, the function will never run and neither hook will do anything. I guess it doesn't really matter in the end though. Both hooks will allow you to set a header. It's like Milo commented on your linked question, one's a filter, one's an action. It's just a matter of how you like to code.

Answer (score 4):

`send_headers` is the preferred method over `wp_headers` for this situation as demonstrated in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers).

```
is_admin() || add_action('send_headers', function(){ 
    header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1'); 
}, 1);
```

Here's [my explanation for why](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214028/43806) on a similar question.