# Does wp_logout_url() destroy a session? (Logging out question)

Tags: login, session

I have a ridiculous issue with logging users out of my site. Basically, the client has sensitive data and when I call `wp_logout_url` I redirect to another url. That's fine, but the browser caches the page and can be seen by pressing *BACK*.

Is there ANY way I can stop this happening, or is it a non-issue that cannot be solved?

The site is protected by a login form on the front end, so it's not /`wp-admin`.

Comment: Where have you seen `$_SESSION` used in core?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, any chance you can elaborate?

Comment: You asked (in the title) "(...) destroy a session".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not surprising or uncommon, it's how browsers work, the pages are cached and are part of the browser history. This is not specific to WordPress but many web applications out there.

There are also different approaches to providing a solution. For one (not very good solution), [clearing the browser history](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout).

For another - sending in special cache headers, like Twitter does. Check out [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for specifics.

[Making sure a web page is not cached across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) is a good starting point, too.

You can add the anti-cache headers for logged in users that will look at sensitive information. All pages with sensitive information would have to have these headers so that browsers can obey them and re-validate upon pressing back after logging out. For everyone else (not logged in) keep browser caching available, which is generally a good idea.

[Setting headers in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers), against [`is_user_logged_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) or [`user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can) is quite straight-forward.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    /* Force no-cache headers on *ALL* front pages and in *ALL* cases */
    /* Proof of concept, do not use */
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' );
    header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    /* Do same for admin_init to get dashboard to not cache */
} );
```

Tested the above and it appears to work, at least in Chrome. Hope this helps. Great question, I wonder why WordPress doesn't force reauthentication on at least the Dashboard pages.

Created ticket to address general Administrator issue: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21938

Comment: +1, I'd do +x if I could. - should be a quick plugin in the meanwhile. Just a note, if I didn't missunderstand this: _"Do same for admin_init"_. Normally the `init` hook is present on both the front as well as the admin side.

Comment: Thanks, @kaiser, I'm a bit rusty on my WordPress-fu, so you're probably right, `init` should handle both cases - front-end and back-end. There's also a [`nocache_headers`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/functions.php#L891) hook available for places where browser caching was not meant to be, which includes all of the Dashboard.

Comment: Ah, nice! From a brief look: The `wp` class and its main function already sends no-cache headers for logged in users and for 404s during `send_headers`. You could intercept them on the `wp_headers`-hook. Guess this could be investigated much further...

Comment: @kaiser, as stated in the ticket http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21938 the missing bit is the "no-store" directive, which most browsers interpret as "OK, I won't cache this page in the history". Also I'm trying it with `init` and it's not working, as if the headers are overwritten after `init`.

Comment: Just added this word-for-word to a member section page template I am using in the Genesis framework. Worked like a charm! The only changes (ok it wasn't completely word for word) is that I couldn't use an anonymous function so I had to separate that out. And I put it in 'genesis_before' so it would work with the genesis framework. Not sure if Genesis will allow you to hook to init. I tried on somethng else and couldn't get it to work. but genesis_before works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not use server-side session storage at all - only cookies (client-side session storage).

And you have no chance to access the web-browser's history...

To disable caching (as stated above) sounds promising - but needs more resources for sure.

Wouldn't do so - simply because the page-speed would suffer for sure.