# If Modified Since HTTP Header

Tags: headers, http

I am trying to enable `304 If Modified Since HTTP header` in my WordPress site. After doing lot of Googling I find out a site where the author said to put the following line at the very end of wordpress `wp-config.php` file. Here is the line of code:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . the_modified_date());
```

Now the author said that this was it. I dont have to do anything else to achieve `304 If Modified Since HTTP header`. But after doing this I tested by HTTP header using the site

> http://httpstatus.io/

and here is the screenshot of my header:

[image]

Check the red marked section. The last modified header value is BLANK.

After that I thought this might be some issue with `the_modified_date()` function so I've also tried `get_the_modified_date()` function. But still no result.

At the very end, I've created a small shortcode function to test if these functions are working or not and echoed it inside the short code. When I used the shortcode I can clearly see that the functions are working fine but for some reason sending blank to the `304 If Modified Since HTTP header`.

My site is [here](http://www.isaumya.com)

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the_modified_date()` is a template tag that must used inside the loop, that is why it is not wokring for you.

WordPress provide a action and filter hook to include or modify HTTP headers:

- [`send_headers` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers)
- [`wp_headers` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/)

But it doesn't work for this purpose. For example, the next code is not working:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'cyb_add_last_modified_header' );
function cyb_add_last_modified_header() {
    //Check if we are in a single post of any type (archive pages has not modified date)
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        if( $post_id ) {
            header("Last-Modified: " . get_the_modified_time("D, d M Y H:i:s", $post_id) );
        }
    }
}
```

**Why?**

The main wp query is not build at this moment, neither in `wp_headers` filter. So, `is_singular()` returns `false`, `get_queried_object_id()` returns `NULL` and there is no way to get the modified time of the current post.

A posible solution is to use [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook, as suggested by Otto in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers) (tested and working):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'cyb_add_last_modified_header');
function cyb_add_last_modified_header($headers) {

    //Check if we are in a single post of any type (archive pages has not modified date)
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        if( $post_id ) {
            header("Last-Modified: " . get_the_modified_time("D, d M Y H:i:s", $post_id) );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I think I better make it a plugin and then use it. Thanks a lot for your help. Also you are checking this for is_single() so will this works for pages and custom post types like portfolios?

Comment: Answer edited to include the correct DateTime format (thanks toscho). For @iSaumya, [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) checks for any type of post, including pages a custom post types. [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) doesn't work for pages and attachments.

Comment: I'm really sorry for previous comments. That was happening due to the part left in `wp-config` file. But actually the above code is not working and not sending the `Last Modified 304` to the header. Check: http://i.imgur.com/LlbxDbB.jpg There is nothing called last modified. I've checking the header of one of my blog post.

Comment: No, it is not working. I've testing and the main WP query seems not to be build as the `send_headers` event, so the `is_singular()` returns `false` and `get_queried_object_id()` returns `NULL`. I didn't expect that the query was not build as this point. I'm now investigating.

Comment: I've found the solution. See edited answer.

Comment: #Awesome. I wish I've enough reputation to up-vote your comment. Sorry mate. Minimum 5 reputation is needed. :)

Comment: Giving wrong date in localized site due to date format: Last-Modified:%D0%A1%D1%80, 31 %D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9 2017 09:25:51

Answer (score 2):

I tried the [code from cybmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172968/83451) but the date wasn't being set correctly. I am not entirely sure the reason, but after investigating I found the [Add Headers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-headers/) plugin which is now deprecated but was a good source of useful code. In that plugin the author sets the Last-Modified header date in a different way and using that to modify the code worked for me. Here is what I ended up with:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'cyb_add_last_modified_header');
function cyb_add_last_modified_header($headers) {
    //Check if we are in a single post of any type (archive pages has not modified date)
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        if( $post_id ) {
            $post_mtime = get_the_modified_time("D, d M Y H:i:s", $post_id);
            $post_mtime_unix = strtotime( $post_mtime );
            $header_last_modified_value = str_replace( '+0000', 'GMT', gmdate('r', $post_mtime_unix) );
            header("Last-Modified: " . $header_last_modified_value );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for **Last-Modified** and correct **304 Not Modified**

### Inside functions.php

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'last_mod_header');

function last_mod_header($headers) {
     if( is_singular() ) {
            $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
            $LastModified = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", $post_id);
            $LastModified_unix = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", $post_id);
            $IfModifiedSince = false;
            if( $post_id ) {
                if (isset($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
                    $IfModifiedSince = strtotime(substr($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 5));  
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
                    $IfModifiedSince = strtotime(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 5));
                if ($IfModifiedSince && $IfModifiedSince >= $LastModified_unix) {
                    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 304 Not Modified');
                    exit;
                } 
     header("Last-Modified: " . get_the_modified_time("D, d M Y H:i:s", $post_id) );
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you explain the code a bit and let users know what it does please?

Comment: This must be a plugin. The theme is for presentation only. You do not want to lose that functionality when you switch themes.

Comment: I agree. You should really explain your code. But toscho I don't think he is asking anyone to put it in a theme. He just shared his code. So if someone thinks that he is not gonna change his theme ever he can use it in functions.php or can add it as a plugin. It's just a function. Anything can be done. But really Travis, you should really explain your code.

Comment: this code gives me Last-Modified date = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT