# How to properly modify WP Vary or any existing headers?

Tags: filters, actions, headers

I have a site that currently have a some part of the headers like:

`Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie`

I want to modify it to be:

`Vary: Accept-Language`

I tried the suggestions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/wp-function-filter-for-modifying-http-headers) using this code

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'mod_header_test' );
   function mod_header_test() {
   header( 'Vary: Accept-Language' );
}
```

But the results I'm getting is:

`Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cookie`

How do I completely erase the existing `Vary` header using the correct action/filter and replace it with: `Vary: Accept-Language` ?